# HTML / CSS - element's weight

Tags: html, css

I'm wondering if there is some kind of weight property in HTML or CSS (or at least a work around).

**I do NOT mean the font-weight.** I mean the size an element can stretch to.

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div weight="1">
  <div weight="2">
</div>
```

In this example the first div should take 1/3 of the width or height (depending on the wrapper's display property and its content's orientation) because the sum of the elements' weight in the wrapper is 3, and the div's weight is 1. Therefore the second div should take 2/3 of the space (weight = 2).

This would be a great way to set the width of elements in a wrapper, if one's width would be relative to the others' ones, and if their amount if dynamic.

Does something like this exist, or do I need to use JS for this?

Comment: use [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) or just write your own CSS classes that will do it.

Comment: Using `%`'s is exactly how you tackle this, just takes simple math to figure out what 2/3 and 1/3 would end up being. Michael's suggestion of Bootstrap is a pretty good idea, at least for learning purposes.

Comment: @DrewKennedy This works until I have a dynamic amount of elements

Comment: I think you need to make that requirement a little more explicit in your question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try [`display: flex;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) on the wrapper and the `flex` property on the child `<div>`s. It should work like you describe the "weight".

> #### `flex: <positive-number>`
>
> Equivalent to `flex: <positive-number> 1 0px`. It makes the flex item
>   flexible and sets the flex basis to zero, resulting in an item that
>   receives the specified proportion of the remaining space.
>
> If all items in the flex container use this pattern, their sizes will
>   be proportional to the specified flex factor.

—   [CSS-tricks about `flex`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex/)

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
.wrapper div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.wrapper div:first-child {
  flex: 1;
}
.wrapper div:nth-child(2) {
  flex: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>test</div>
  <div>test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, I'm using `display:flex` a lot, but I actually didn't know about the `flex` property. That's exactly, what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to write your own CSS, there are CSS frameworks and libraries that will give you this functionality. Here's an example using [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox allows you to set "weights" by shrink/grow values. Here's a link to a thorough walkthrough on all the properties: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

By setting the second to `flex-grow: 2` and the first to `flex-grow: 1` you'll get twice the growth out of the second, or 2/3 and 1/3.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
.weighed {
  height: 50px;
  border: 5px solid white;
}

.weight1 {
  flex: 1;
  background: green;
}

.weight2 {
  flex: 2;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="weighed weight1"></div>
  <div class="weighed weight2"></div>
</div>
```